# pabot :: Is it possible to use same valuesets in parallel pabot process?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

i have some robotframework tests and i am trying to parallelize these tests using pabot (pabot.pabotlib). since pabot requires valuesset.dat and i have only 1 valueset (credential) which i want to use in multiple processes at same time, is it possible to use same valueset in multiple porcesses.

Ex. ; Can it be done this way ?

test.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library pabot.PabotLib
*** Test Case ***
Testing PabotLib
Acquire Lock MyLock
Log This part is critical section
Release Lock MyLock
${valuesetname}= Acquire Value Set
${host}= Get Value From Set host
${username}= Get Value From Set username
${password}= Get Value From Set password
Log Do something with the values (for example access host with username and    password)
Release Value Set
Log After value set release others can obtain the variable values
```

valueset.dat

```
[Server1]
HOST=123.123.123.123
USERNAME=user1
PASSWORD=password1

[Server2]
HOST=121.121.121.121
USERNAME=user1
PASSWORD=password1
```

pabot call

```
pabot --pabotlib --resourcefile valueset.dat test.robot
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Value Sets? If you only have 1 set of credentials, you can just put it in robotframework variables as in : `${host}=121.121.121.121      ${username}= user1
     ${password}= password1` inside the test suite. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you insist on using Value Sets, just make a bunch of identical ones: `[Server1]
HOST=123.123.123.123
USERNAME=user1
PASSWORD=password1`, `[Server2]
HOST=123.123.123.123
USERNAME=user1
PASSWORD=password1`

Comment: Thanks Jim. I have 1 set of credentials which i want to use as valueset for all pabot parallel processes

Comment: I didn't quite understand you. Was any of my answers helpful? Will you accept it if I post it formally?

Comment: I have already tried your 2nd suggestion of creating bunch on identical value sets and it does not work for me. I am not sure how can we implement/use what you are advising on 1st comment

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have to do 1 login and use that data for multiple tests with Pabot.

1. Use a Python file to launch Pabot as a subprocess (say, run_my_tests.py)
2. In that file, create a function that does your setup. Could be as elaborate as you wish. Make sure it creates all the necessary data. That data can be placed into a dictionary or list or something.
3. Pickle the data. This preserves the object in a file.
4. In the run_my_tests.py, setup pabot arguments as a list including pabot itself. For example:

   pabot_command = ['pabot', '--processes', '10', '--variable', 'TEST_ENV:dev']
5. Make sure pabot_command includes '--variablefile' followed by 'variables.py' . This is the file that each Robot thread will invoke.
6. Create variables.py file in your directory where the run_my_tests.py is.
7. In the variables.py file, place code similar to this:

   ```
   import pickle

   def get_variables(): 
   with open("auth_data.pkl", 'rb') as auth_data_file:
       cookies = pickle.load(auth_data_file)
   variables = {"AUTH_COOKIES": cookies}
   return variables
   ```

This will read your saved data from the pickled file and pass it into the thread. Each thread will call this file once, extracting your data from one central place.
get_variables() is the function named by convention in Robot Framework that sets up variables for a Robot run